# user-login-checker simple (bash) script

Tags: bash, scripting

I'm very new to bash scripting (I program in python) but sometimes I need to run some simple script on my ubuntu (at work) so I started learning bash scripting.

Anyway, I would like to create a script that would take 2 arguments (start and end time) and would give as result users that were logged in between that time. It would also say how many times they logged in and the combined time they were logged in.

example:

```
$./run 25/4 20/5 <br />
joe 4x 3 days and 11:45 <br />
bob 2x 0 days and 2:17 <br />
smith 17x 21 days and 23:17 <br />
```

so the first column says what user it is, 2nd says how many times he logged in in the system, the 3rd-6th it shows the combined time he was logged. The data is limited to the time from 25/4 to 20/5 (the arguments)

I have some clues but they are all "ugly". Again I'm a python programmer so I'm used to having "pretty" solutions.

I was thinking to do this by using `last` and then just parse the text...

Any code hints would be helpful

best k.

Comment: I cannot think any reason about why you can't do it in python as is what you like best. Just create a python script that parses the output of `last -F` and renders what you want to achieve.

Comment: the whole point in doing this is to learn bash script. if i do this in python that would defeat the purpose.

Comment: I understand your point, however to do what you want to do you'll need shell tools like `sed`, `awk`, `grep`, etc which aren't strictly bash, to parse the `last` output. Hence, if you know python best, use it to parse the stuff. Python, perl, ruby, are as valid power shell tools as are `sed`, `awk`, et al.

Answer (score 1):

The bash script below will do most of what you want and I think it has enough content to be helpful to you. However, I really don't think this kind of thing should be done in bash. Personally, I prefer the native output of `last` to the output you described.

One of the big problems with the script below is that it isn't very portable. It works on my Ubuntu 11.04 workstation, but not my RHEL 4 workstation (older awk version is not compatible with how I specified the delimiters).

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

for user in $(last | head -n-2 | cut -d' ' -f1 | sort | uniq); do
  echo -n $user $(last | head -n-2 | cut -d' ' -f1 | grep "^$user$" | wc -l)x
  hours=$(last | head -n-2 | grep "^$user\b" | awk '{ print $NF }' | grep -v '^in$' | awk -F'[\(\):]' '{ print $2 }' | paste -sd+ | bc)
  minutes=$(last | head -n-2 | grep "^$user\b" | awk '{ print $NF }' | grep -v '^in$' | awk -F'[\(\):]' '{ print $3 }' | paste -sd+ | bc)

  days=$(( ($hours + $minutes / 60) / 24 ))
  hours=$(( ($hours + $minutes / 60) % 24 ))
  minutes=$(( $minutes % 60 ))
  echo -n " $days days and $hours:$minutes"

  if last | head -n-2 | grep "^$user\b" | grep -qs "still logged in"; then
    echo -n ', still logged in'
  fi
  echo
done
```